# phonegap video not working in iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I've been fooling around with this for so long and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Everyone says to use the HTML5 video tag for phonegap if you're in iOS, but I keep getting the broken video tag when I launch my app in iOS. It works fine on the web, but not in iOS. Here is my code:

```
<video id='player' controls src="videos/sample-video.mp4"></video>
```

I'm starting to think that this doesn't work because of the new version of phonegap. I'm using version 3.0.0-0.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i fixed my own issue. the video codec was H.264 and I guess that's unsupported so I got a video with lower quality and it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<video id="yourid" width="1024" height="768" controls>
      <source src="yoursource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: no it still doesn't work. i'm starting to think its the version of phonegap i'm using

Comment: it actually was good code, i was just using an unsupported video format